# Remove letter of detached vdisk?

Tags: windows-8.1, diskpart

Normally, one attaches and detaches a virtual hard drive like this

```
C:\> diskpart
select vdisk file=path_to_vdisk.vhd
attach vdisk // vdisk attached as volume n
select volume n
assign letter=V
exit

C:\> REM Do some stuff in V:\

C:\> diskpart
select volume n
remove letter=V
select vdisk file=path_to_vdisk.vhd
detach vdisk
exit
```

But how to remove the drive letter **after** detaching the vdisk? I often forget to remove the drive letter first, so I am left with a zombie drive letter, which can neither be removed by `remove letter=V` nor be reassigned using

```
attach vdisk
select volume n // n might have changed
assign letter=V
```

So far, the only way I know to remove the zombie drive letter is to restart the system, but is there a different way`(one that does not involve restarting the system)?

Comment: The solution to your problem is to remove the drive letter before you dismount the virtual HDD

Comment: @Ramhound So there is no other way?

Comment: This will sometimes happen with network drives I have found.  Restarting File Explorer might be enough.

Comment: @Ramhound Restarting explorer.exe (`taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` followed by `explorer.exe`) didn't work.

Comment: Does diskmgmt.msc allow it to be unmounted?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nope. In fact, it doesn't even show the drive letter for this specific volume (even if the vdisk is still attached and the drive letter still assigned. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that the volume is an (inactive) EFI system partition.)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Just to clarify: diskpart shows the drive letter and I can access it with the file explorer, but diskmgmt.msc does not shot the drive letter. Instead, it just lists it as an unnamed and letter-less volume.